# Setting headers in hapi.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi.js

I am new to hapi.js, can any one explain me how i can configure custom variables for each route and I should be able to access those custom variables on 'onPreHandler'

And how i can add headers just before calling reply.continue.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read [Hapi tutorials](https://hapijs.com/tutorials), specifically [Routing](https://hapijs.com/tutorials/routing) for intro about path parameters:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/hello/{user}',
    handler: function (request, h) {
        return `Hello ${encodeURIComponent(request.params.user)}!`;
    }
});
```

Same way you can access path parameters in `onPreHandler`:

```
server.ext('onRequest', function (request, h) {
  console.log(request.params.user)
  return h.continue;
})
```

[Setting headers](https://hapijs.com/api#-hresponsevalue) can be done like this:

```
const handler = function (request, h) {
    const response = h.response('success');
    response.header('X-Custom', 'some-value');
    return response;
};
```